# TIFF IRM Protector

Tags: 2010, records-management, ecm, irm

I know by default, SP 2010 does not have a TIFF IRM protector.

Before trying to write a TIFF protector, if such a protector is already available could someone point me to it.

Comment: I think the issue you will find is that for IRM to work, the filetype needs to be IRM-aware. The custom IRM protector documentation you'll find is to apply IRM to filetypes that you have created. If I have a picture viewer that is not IRM aware (http://www.pictview.com/), will it still be able to open the TIFF? Will the TIFF still be a properly formatted TIFF?

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint's facilitates IRM for MS Office-related documents. For other app documents (e.g., PDF & TIFF), it will have to be custom-built or provided by 3rd party vendors (e.g., NextLabs). There are provisions for [Custom Protectors within SharePoint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms439253.aspx) where one can build their own protectors.

Comment: This doesn't really answer OP's question -- OP was asking if there was already a 3rd party TIFF IRM protector so they would not have to go to the trouble of writing one.

Comment: I don't want to push 3rd party commercial products here (as per forum rules) but have cited an example (NextLabs) and the alternative of custom development for providing SharePoint IRM features..